# How do I turn every element on a page into a scrolling marquee?

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there something I can do to a web application that would turn every div into a scrolling marquee? Maybe a CSS class or something? It's Angular 4 and bootstrap.

Comment: Maybe look into [css animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) or [css transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). Hard to answer without more details.

Comment: Predictably? No, not without a ridiculous amount of work because who knows the different permutations of Parent->Child box model relationships in how `<div>` elements may be used within the DOM and their display and positioning attributes. More importantly though, why would you want to?

Comment: It's just for fun to see what it looks like. Maybe I'll push to production to see if anyone notices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following demo is a Pure CSS Solution **[using CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)**.

---

### Demo

```css
.marquee {
  width: 60%;
  /* Required on Parent */
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 400 32px/1.5 Consolas;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.marquee b {
  /* Required on Child*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-cell;
  color: cyan;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  /* Infinite Loops */
  animation: rightToLeft 12s linear infinite;
  /* Right to left direction */
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  /* Set to 0s in order to have a point of reference */
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.marquee b a {
  color: gold
}


/* Required for complex CSS animation */

@keyframes rightToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='marquee'>
  <b>You should read <i>“how to ask”</i>:&nbsp;<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask">https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask</a></b>
</div>

<div class='marquee'>
  <b>You can change the CSS ".marquee" class selector to "div" and then sit back and watch the chaos unfold.</b>
</div>

<div class='marquee'>
  <b>Making every div a scrolling marquee seems excessive and pointless.</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the marquee html element? Do note this is deprecated.

```html
<marquee>This text will scroll from right to left</marquee>

<marquee direction="up">This text will scroll from bottom to top</marquee>

<marquee direction="down" width="250" height="200" behavior="alternate" style="border:solid">
  <marquee behavior="alternate">
    This text will bounce
  </marquee>
</marquee>
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: This element is [deprecated](https://caniuse.com/#search=marquee) and shouldn't be used regardless.

Comment: Marquee's are a bad idea regardless, but that doesn't mean we can't help them with ideas.

Comment: @rawnewdlz sure, but don't give answers with deprecated code without at least mentioned that the method is deprecated.

Comment: This is true, any time help is offered is awesome, just pointing out the deprecation to deter the practice for other readers. Oh, and I wasn't the one that down-voted ya in case ya wondered. Cheers